# How to make Firebase Invites work on emulator?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am testing [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites) from an emulator based on tutorial from official site.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
```

Emulator used:

> CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 28)
>
> Skin: pixel_2

I try to call activity for result like this.

```
private void onInviteClicked() {
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
            .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
            .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
```

But in activityOnResult I always get Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED as a result code.

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the invitation IDs of all sent messages
        String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
        for (String id : ids) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: sent invitation " + id);
        }
    } else {
        // Sending failed or it was canceled, show failure message to the user
        // ...
    }
}
```

It turns out that it is because there is a crash in invites library:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 10555
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.appinvite.intent.action.INVITE_SENT cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteChimeraActivity$AppInviteResponseReceiver@d32d00e
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0(LoadedApk.java:1401)
    at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@93c43be -- permission denied for window type 2003
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:822)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at fzg.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):22)
    at fzg.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):15)
    at fzg.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteChimeraActivity.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):91)
    at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteChimeraActivity$AppInviteResponseReceiver.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):2)
    at xbc.onReceive(:com.google.android.gms@14366040@14.3.66 (100700-213742215):1)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0(LoadedApk.java:1391)
    at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This happens only on emulator and not on physical device.

Anyone knows how to make Firebase Invites work also on emulator?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Not only emulators, Android 8.0 newer devices also have this problem?
It seems that this problem is based on the window, which is used by SnackBar in Firebase Invites library.

Answer (score 2):

[WindowManager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams) constant `2003` is `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, deprecated in API level 26. either build against API 25 (which may be that physical device) or use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead. with a single line from the `build.gradle` it's difficult to understand against which API the code even runs.

hint: make sure you run this on an emulator image with Play Services installed.

Comment: I have updated the question, but it looks like it is an issue of Firebase Invite library. Not much I can do here.